# Preposition placement mid-sentence

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

I was recently reviewing a piece of writing for a friend of mine who wrote

> Though such a theory does not describe the world we live in, it will undoubtedly shed
>   light on...

I told him to change this to

> Though such a theory does not describe the world in which we live, it will undoubtedly shed light on...

I'm not entirely sure why I think this is correct besides the indirect evidence obtained from recalling that one is not supposed to end a sentence with a preposition.

Was I correct?  Is there a general, corresponding rule?  If so, what is it?

Comment: The general rule is to ignore the advice you learned from a narrow minded grammarian, and feel free to use a preposition to end a sentence with. Or as one writer put it: "This is the sort of bloody nonsense up with which I will not put." http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/churchill.html

Comment: @MετάEd That's the sort of rule I can really vibe with :)

Comment: Were you correct? Yes & No! Both forms are fine. To my mind, the first is slightly more natural.

Comment: These crazy young people nowadays; they say the darndest things.  Why the other day, my daughter asked me, "Dad, do you want to come with?"  Of course I responded, "Where and with whom?"  Kids.  You can't live with 'em and you can't kill 'em.

Answer (score 2):

Either way works fine.

That being said, you have to read it in context with the surrounding passages.  I would say that the former might be slightly better in a more casual setting, and the latter in a more formal, in that it sounds slightly more formal.

But the real question is: how does it sound in the place where it is used?  That alone should govern, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

The rule against prepositions at the end of clauses was meant to prevent expressions like "*where is my car at?" The test is whether you can remove the word and still have a valid sentence. The segment really is the clause, not the sentence. "*If I knew where my car was at, I'd still need my car keys" has the same problem as the original.

I think your friend's first sentence was much better than what you had him change it to.